# Wordpress Gutenberg home page "edit Page" option missing

Tags: editor, block-editor

I try to understand customising of default theme, in my case twenty nineteen. After I create a new page on the top horizontal bar there is an option "Edit Page" visible. Why that option is missing on the bar for home page?

What is the best way to customise the home page?

Home page:
[image]

New page:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The posts page, which is always `index.php` (main template) of your theme, cannot be edited by neither, `Guttenberg` nor `Classic Editor`.

Create a child theme, and copy `index.php` from your parent theme to the child theme. Then you can edit your child's `index.php`, using external text editor.